# Erro na hora de inserir uma imagem no Oracle usando PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, imagem, oracle

Estou fazendo um sistema em `PDO` `PHP` que grava algumas imagens no banco de dados, esse mesmo sistema foi migrado de uma base de dados `MySQL` e estava funcionando perfeitamente, porém na hora que vou gravar a imagem em um coluna do tipo `BLOB` no `Oracle` me retorna a seguinte exceção:

> [Thu Mar 02 13:11:37.290759 2017] [:error] [pid 5740:tid 2192] [client
>   ::1:54413] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 972 OCIStmtPrepare:
>   **ORA-00972:** identificador muito longo\n (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:339)' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ManutencaoOracle\administrador.php:1581\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ManutencaoOracle\administrador.php(1581):
>   PDO->exec('insert into equ...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ManutencaoOracle\administrador.php on line 1581,
>   referer: http://localhost:81/ManutencaoOracle/administrador.php

Segue o insert no banco de dados :

> `$query = $con->exec("insert into equipamentos (id,grupo,quantidade,descricao,marca_modelo,patrimonio,serie,tipo_ponto,foto_acabamento,foto_maquina) values (".$maior_id.",'".$_POST['labelGrupo']."',".$_POST['labelQuantidades'].",'".$_POST['labelDescricao']."','".$_POST['labelMarcaModelo']."',".$_POST['labelPatrimonio'].",'".$_POST['labelSerie']."','".$foto_ponto_certa."','".$foto_acabamentos_certa."','".$foto_maquina_certa."')");`

Create da tabela:

> `CREATE TABLE equipamentos (id INTEGER NOT NULL,grupo VARCHAR2(50),quantidade INTEGER,descricao VARCHAR2(50),marca_modelo VARCHAR2(50),patrimonio INTEGER,serie VARCHAR2(50), tipo_ponto BLOB, foto_acabamento BLOB, foto_maquina BLOB,PRIMARY KEY (id))`

Tratamento das imagens com php antes da inserção no banco de dados:

```
// ARMAZENA A PRIMEIRA FOTO NOS ARRAYS
$foto_ponto = $_FILES['fotoPonto']['tmp_name'];
$foto_ponto_tamanho = $_FILES['fotoPonto']['size'];
$foto_ponto_tipo = $_FILES['fotoPonto']['type'];
$foto_ponto_nome = $_FILES['fotoPonto']['name'];


// TRATA A PRIMEIRA FOTO PARA FAZER A INSERÇÃO DELA NO BANCO DE DADOS
$fp = @fopen($foto_ponto, "rb");
$conteudo = @fread($fp,$foto_ponto_tamanho);
$foto_ponto_certa = @addslashes($conteudo);
@fclose($fp);
```

***Observações:***

- coloquei só tratamento só da primeira foto pra não ficar muito extenso, o tratamento de todas as fotos são iguais.
- esse mesmo código funciona perfeitamente em uma base de dados `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, sugiro você refatorar um pouco mais, já que trocou do MySQL para Oracle e está inserindo registro com campo LOB. Segue uma sugestão didática:

```
$conn = ocilogon('usuario','senha','nome_da_base');

$arquivo  = "Open Office.zip";
$handle   = fopen($arquivo, "rb");
$conteudo = fread($handle, filesize($arquivo));

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO TABELA_BLOB VALUES (EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING ANEXO INTO :ANEXO");
$blob_aux = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":ANEXO", &$blob_aux, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
$blob_aux->save($conteudo);

if (ocicommit($conn)) {
   echo "Registro inserido OK.";
} else {
   echo "ERRO, registro não inserido.";
}
```

Comment: Não estou usando o oci, estou usando PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
<?php

   include '../conexao_oracle.php';

   $db->beginTransaction(); // VERY IMPORTANT !
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
       "INSERT INTO equipamentos (foto_ponto) ".
       "VALUES (EMPTY_BLOB()) ".
       "RETURNING foto_pontoINTO :foto_ponto");
   $stmt->bindParam(':foto_ponto', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
   $blob = fopen($foto_ponto, "rb");
   $stmt->execute();
   $db->commit();
```